# Find value of k for distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix

$$
A =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
k & 3 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$

where k is an arbitrary constant. For which values of k does A have three distinct real eigenvalues? For which k does A have two distinct eigenvalues?

Hint: Graph the function 
$$
g(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 3\lambda
$$

Find its local maxima and minima.

So far I've tried this:

Let
$$
B = A - \lambda * I = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & 1 \\
k & 3 & -\lambda \end{array} \right)
$$
where I is the identity matrix.

Then:

$$
p(\lambda) = det(B) = -\lambda^3 + 3\lambda + k
$$

Then I found the critical points by setting the derivative to 0.

$$
p'(\lambda) = -3\lambda^2 + 3 = 0 \\
\lambda = 1 \\
\lambda = -1 
$$

Plugging this back into the original equation I got
$$
p(1) = -1^3 + 3(1) + k > 0 \\
p(-1) = 1^3 + 3(-1) + k < 0 \\
$$

This gave me the values of k
$$
k > -2 \\
k < 2
$$

This is only one set of values for k. Is the value of k such that there are three distinct real eigenvalues or two? Also, if this is correct, how do I find the other set of values for k? <strike>And finally, did I missing something since the hint gave me an equation that I didn't find. I'm not really sure where that equation came from.</strike>

Edit: I realize where that equation that's given in the hint came from. I didn't realize it was the characteristic polynomial that I calculated but just in a different form.

Comment: The characteristic equation is $-\lambda^3 + 3\lambda + k = 0$.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I'm not really sure what to do with that. I was under the impression that you had to solve for lambda first, but you can't with just that equation

Comment: Two distinct eigenvalues is for $p'(\lambda)=0$ then $p(\lambda)=0$ has only 2 solutions for values of $k$, as graph is tangent to the $p=0$ line at these points of intersection (they are "doubled")

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin So what I've done so far is finding k for two distinct eigenvalues right? If so, then how do I find k for three distinct eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the characteristic equation is $$3\lambda - \lambda^3 = k.$$ the graph has a local max  $(1,2)$ and local min at $(-1-2).$

so if $$ -2 < k < 2, \text{the char equation has three distinct roots}\\
 k = \pm 2, \text{the char equation has a repeated real root}\\
|k| >2 \text{char equation has one real root and two complex conjugate roots.}$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Just to clarify, this means that by increasing the range of k, there are more distinct roots right?

Comment: @user3370201,   you have three distinct roots for $k$ in the range $-2$ to $2.$

Answer (score 2):

By plotting $p(\lambda)$ for the case where $k = 0$, we obtain the following curve:

[image]

By varying $k$, we are free to move the curve up or down. Now recall that having three distinct real eigenvalues corresponds to making $p(\lambda)$ cross the horizontal axis exactly three times. By computing the local extrema, notice that this can happen by vertically translating up by no more than $2$ units or vertically translating down by no more than $2$ units. So $k \in (-2, 2)$ corresponds to three distinct real eigenvalues and $k \in \{-2, 2\}$ corresponds to two distinct real eigenvalues and $k \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (2, \infty)$ corresponds to one real eigenvalue.